# Is there a preferred way of restarting X after getting stuck on the desktop despite not logging in due to disconnecting a monitor?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xorg, xfce, xubuntu

When I disconnect the external monitor on my Xubuntu 20.04 laptop, I occasionally experience some misbehavior on my main monitor. For example, I recently disconnected my external monitor while the machine was sleeping. Upon waking it, I had a fraction of a second to try to log in before I was sent to my desktop screen with only the ability to move the mouse. `pkill`ing my session with another tty does the trick, as would REISUB, but this seems extreme. Keyboard shortcuts on the main tty, such as Super+L to lock the screen and get me back the the log-in screen, appear to get ignored.

Ultimately, my question is this: If my XFCE4 X session is misbehaving and is ignoring most keyboard inputs, what's the preferred way to restart it? My current means, e.g. `pkill` seem like I'm turning to the weapons of last resort as a first resort.

Comment: SIGTERM (which is normally the default signal send by pkill) is quite a proper way to "stop" an X server though. Depending on how you start it, the other way could be terminating its "main" client (xfce). You can also try `--off` in `xrandr` (I don't exactly remember if it will cause X to kill itself if the specified `--output` is the only one left on; in case it won't, you can see if turning it back on with `--on` helps; you probably want to run the two instances of xrandr command in one list; with a short `sleep` in between perhaps?)

Comment: If you are using a display manager and systemd, perhaps `terminate-session` in `loginctl` is a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem might be related to the bug report
[Session crashes when monitor is disconnected](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1733127).
This bug report was marked as duplicate of another bug report:
[Artful (17.10) Session logout after screen turned off](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-shell/+bug/1721428),
which was closed after the poster solved his problem by moving to Wayland.

As regarding unfreezing an X session, here is a summary from the article
[4 Ways to Recover From a Crashed or Frozen X Server on Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/119293/4-ways-to-recover-from-a-crashed-or-frozen-x-server-on-linux/).

**1. Ctrl+Alt+Backspace**

The Ctrl+Alt+Backspace keyboard shortcut that traditionally restarted
the X server is disabled by default. To enable it on a
GNOME-based desktop, use the Keyboard Layout utility.
Click the Options button and enable the "Control + Alt + Backspace"
check-box under "Key sequence to kill the X server".

**2. Restart the X server from terminal**

To restart the X server, log into a virtual console and run the command:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

**3. SSH into computer**

If you can't log into a virtual console, and the SSH server is
active, you may be able to enter the above *restart* command
from another computer.

**4. The SysRq key**

If the X server has taken control of the keyboard,
to take it back use the following key combination:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
Now you could try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 to access a virtual console.