# What to do when my machine is locked, but the desktop is showing?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xfce, xubuntu, lock-screen, ubuntu-22.04

Sometimes, on my Xubuntu 22.04 laptop, I'll unplug the dual monitor, leave the machine, and then attempt to log back in without plugging the monitor back in.

Due to an unknown fault, this sometimes sends me to the lock screen for a matter of seconds before I'm suddenly taken back to my Desktop (even if I've yet to finish typing my password in) and able to see my mouse move but be unable to click on anything. Sometimes, typing my password and pressing enter lets me escape this trap and lets me continue on as normal. I can use keyboard shortcuts to enter another TTY, but keyboard shortcuts for locking the screen does nothing. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> also does nothing. I don't recall what plugging the monitor back in does, but I know that it doesn't help.

When trapped like this, is there a standard way to return to the lock screen *without restarting X*?

I don't quite have the steps for replicating this fault, but my question is only regarding how to fix it once it's happened rather than prevent it, so that should be a non-issue. All that I know is that it's got something to do with unplugging a dual monitor and either locking or sleeping the machine.

I can sometimes intentionally trigger the issue by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

[This other SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/q/1662470/865660) covers how to solve the problem by restarting X, but that's not what I'm asking for here.

Clearly, X hasn't crashed if I can sometimes unlock the screen and return to everything working as it should be after unlocking.

Comment: Remark : You might be interested in more methods for [restarting X](https://superuser.com/a/1686233/8672). This link also points to posts with the advice to use Wayland for working around such problems.

Comment: @harrymc I'm on XFCE, which as far as I know has no Wayland version.

Comment: (1) Some posts indicated to unfreeze by signalling xfce4-panel to reload itself : `killall -USR1 xfce4-panel`. (2) An [article](https://linuxreviews.org/Linux_Kernel_5.5_Will_Not_Fix_The_Frequent_Intel_GPU_Hangs_In_Recent_Kernels) says that starting with the 5.1 kernel, there is a problem with Intel processors that have integrated graphics. If that's your case, you may need to downgrade your kernel to version 4.

Answer (score 2):

What is your setup? Are you using the default XFCE Desktop Environment?

Did you use `xfce4-panel-profiles` to set up dual monitors?

Are you using `xfce4-screensaver`?

It happened to me in the past that two different programs were locking the screen, because I didn't have a good understanding how the Desktop Environment was distinct from the Window Manager, and that basically every functionality that I was used to as being part of the OS (like on Windows) can be covered by a different program, and they can even overlap, which can cause unintended side-effects.

Comment: I believe that I'm using panel profiles. xfce4-screensaver-preferences shows that my screensaver is disabled, but "Lock Screen with Screensaver" is enabled.

Comment: Can you check that you don't have `XScreenSaver` and `light-locker` installed?

I've found two related questions, the first one seems to describe the issues I was having:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304681/xubuntu-20-04-two-lock-screens-after-idle

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233858/xubuntu-20-04-suspend-waits-30-seconds

You could try to look through some of the suggestions there first.

Comment: I'm confident that neither are installed.

Comment: could you clarify the description more?

when you write: "leave the machine, and then attempt to log back in" – does that mean that `xfce4-power-manager` locks the screen because of inactivity?

I think you will need to go to the terminal and get all the logs and verbosity you can get to find what programs are running and what errors there are in the logs to find out exactly what is happening.

https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/faq – see how to start in debug mode. Assuming this is what is happening. Please give us more details and proof from the command line.

Comment: @J.Mini could you also post `lightdm` logs? See this post for more details: https://askubuntu.com/a/396976/488733

See also here to get your config file and multiple monitor setup file: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM

Comment: also could you post the system logs from `journalctl` while your reproduce the issue and just cut out the relevant lines

Comment: I've discovered that I can trigger the issue immediately by restarting X with `ctrl+alt+backspace`. Only the logs in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` showed anything at the relevant time. See anything of interest? https://pastebin.com/079TtdSX

Comment: The only thing I though of was to update or disable the Intel drivers, but then I read the question again. I'm posting a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a new answer, because I have misunderstood the question.

If I understand correctly Xubuntu uses `lightdm`, and therefore it does not have a "lock screen" shortcut set up by default.

Here's a guide on how to set up the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or [Super](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-key-super.html.en) in Ubuntu land) shortcut for locking the screen:

[Lock screen after switching from GDM to LightDM](https://www.perfacilis.com/blog/systeembeheer/linux/lock-screen-after-switching-from-gdm-to-lightdm.html)

Comment: I don't see the relevance of this answer. I've had a Windows+L shortcut set up for a long time on Xubuntu. It does nothing when I'm suffering from this issue.