# How do I restart the X server in Xubuntu?

Tags: linux, ssh, xubuntu, x-server

I have a server whose screen has gone blank.  It is running, and I can get into it with SSH, but the main console is dark.  I cannot get to a command-line with Ctl-Alt-F1 as usual either.  I had luck in the distant past restarting X, and would like to try that, but am not sure how on modern systems.

How do I restart the X service (since I can do it over SSH).

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1662470/is-there-a-preferred-way-of-restarting-x-after-getting-stuck-on-the-desktop-desp) solve the problem?

Comment: @harrymc  GENIUS!  Yes it does, or I should say the lightdm one does -- the others did not.  I suspected this would be the case, and tried it last.  Thank you very much.